# The starter button on my 2008 United Motors V2S 250R stopped working. Could I just buy any other starter for it?

Tags: starter

Can I just get any other starter for it or does it have to be from that brand

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is it your starter or the button which is bad?

Comment: Or the wiring...

Comment: Or the battery?

Comment: Im pretty sure it’s the button becase it doesn’t make anything noise when I push it

Comment: @SantosCortez so test it with a multimeter before buying one in error.